# How can i embed my function in the button to operate on click?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<span>Generate Activation Request File</span>
                                <input type="submit" value="Generate"  class="submit" id="submit"/>
```

that is the button i need to integrate my function with, how can i do it so it does what the function generate_request_file() is supposed to achieve when clicked (onclick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add onclick in you input tag

```
<input type="submit" value="Generate" onclick="generate_request_file()" class="submit" id="submit"/>
```